# Change VS2010 Default ItemTemplates path?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Using VS2010 - I already know how to edit the default code templates.  What I am looking for is a way to modify the path that VS2010 points to for these templates.  The default path, if you are running 64 bit, is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033

I have a requirement where there are multiple developers on a team - and we want the templates to be in one central location - in our case, on a network.  The only idea that comes to mind is changing the default VS2010 template path.  Does anyone know if this is feasible?

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article is about Visual Studio 2005 but might be anyhow interesting for you, because the workflow should be generally the same:

- [Create Reusable Project And Item Templates For Your Development Team](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188697.aspx)